# Password checker in Java 5 characters min and must start with a vowel

Tags: java

I am making a password checker in Java and am getting a syntax error on line 23 and don't know why.

This is the line of code that has the syntax error: `char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);`. On this line, I am setting the first letter of the user input to a variable so I can test if it is a vowel or not.

```
import java.util.*;

public class week2LoopsProgram {
    
    public static final int MINIMUIM_LENGTH = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello! You must enter a word to pass.");
        System.out.println("The word must be at least 5 characters long ");
        System.out.println("and must begin with an upper or lowercase vowel.");
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your word below:");
        
        String word = scan.nextLine();
        
        int length = word.length();
        
        boolean correctLength = length >= MINIMUIM_LENGTH;
        
        char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
                
        boolean vowelCheck(char firstLetter) {
            switch (firstLetter) {
                case 'a':            
                case 'e':           
                case 'i':           
                case 'o':            
                case 'u':            
                case 'A':
                case 'E':            
                case 'I':           
                case 'O':            
                case 'U':
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot define a method inside another method. You are trying to define the method `boolean vowelCheck(char firstLetter)` inside your `public static void main(String[] args)` method. That's not valid in java.

Comment: It should be `MINIMUM_LENGTH` btw

Comment: Have you considered vowels like é, Å, œ?

Comment: I'm guessing this is an exercise, but just fyi it could be just `boolean valid = candidate.matches("(?i)[aeiou].{4,}");`

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I assume this is just a learning exercise. Otherwise, you should not be restricting the characters allowed in a password as that makes it easier to guess.

As noted in the comment, you can't define a method inside another method in Java (even though you can in many other languages). However, what you can do instead is just have `vowelCheck` as a variable instead of a method, and assign it using the new switch expression syntax available in recent versions of the Java compiler:

```
    boolean vowelCheck = switch (firstLetter) {
        case 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' -> true;
        default -> false;
    };
```